# Heatmap from qualitative frequencies in R

Tags: r, visualization, heatmap

I'm wondering if it's possible to create a heatmap like this. [image]

I explored heatmap() for some time yesterday and was unable to even create the heatmap, let alone with styling like this, so I made it from scratch. However, I will have to make more... does anyone have a solution to creating something like this?
My data is just the answers to each question (in numerical form, so Never = 1, oncexweek = 2, etc) and looks like this (all columns numeric):

```
                      Q1                     Q2                 Q3                   Q4
1                      3                      1                  3                    3
2                      5                      5                  5                    5
3                     NA                      1                 NA                   NA
5                      3                      3                  5                    5
7                      5                      1                  3                    5
8                      5                      4                  3                    4
10                     1                      5                  1                    1
11                     2                      1                  2                    1
13                     3                      2                  3                    2
14                     3                     NA                  5                   NA
15                     3                      3                  1                    1...etc
......................................
```

I would greatly appreciate any ideas here. Additionally, I kind of arbitrarily determined the breaks for the colors based on a binned histogram... what's a better way to do that @statpeeps :)

Comment: does `skip` mean NA?

Comment: Maybe you can try to use `replace_na` function, then by using `table` function to construct a better data format for visualization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are happy to replace the NA's with 0, something like:
(using tidyverse functions and the base R `heatmap()`)

```
df |> pivot_longer(cols = everything(),
                   names_to = "Question",
                   values_to = "Answer") |>
  count(Question, Answer) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = Question,
              values_from = n) |>
  column_to_rownames("Answer") |>
  as.matrix() |> t() |>
  heatmap()
```

gives a basic:

[image]

info here about changing the look / labelling etc to suit:

https://r-graph-gallery.com/215-the-heatmap-function.html

### ggplot version

Start point for `ggplot()` version using `geom_tile()`:

```
df |> pivot_longer(cols = everything(),
                   names_to = "Question",
                   values_to = "Answer") |>
  count(Question, Answer) |>
  ggplot(data = _, aes(x = Answer, y = Question, fill = n)) + 
  geom_tile() + # heatmap
  geom_text(aes(label = n)) + # add the counts to each tile
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 0:5,
                   labels = c("Skipped","Never / almost never",
                              "Once per week",
                              "2-3 times per week",
                              "Once per day",
                              "Multiple times per day")) # relabel x axis
```

gives:
[image]

### my sample data:

```
set.seed(12345)
df <- data.frame(Q1 = sample(0:5, 20, TRUE),
                 Q2 = sample(0:5, 20, TRUE),
                 Q3 = sample(0:5, 20, TRUE),
                 Q4 = sample(0:5, 20, TRUE))
```